# Angular - displaying table elements according to true/false checkbox element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes and table. My goal is to hide specific element in a table when specific checkbox is set to false.

For example: When I press 'Id' -> '20' should disappear (stackblitz example)

I get data from API (json file). My idea was to create a second array with names and statuses (set default to true -> to display checkboxes) to display list of checkboxes.

But I don't know how to connect this, so elements of table can be displayed according to checked/unchecked checkbox.

Here is my [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json-working-txntps)

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: By looking your table, it seems you already know all the column names. Then why do you retrieve them in an other array and iterate over them?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json-working-g7kkob

Answer (score 1):

Use and object like status to keep track of column status:

```
status =  {
    id: false,
    email: true,
    login: true,
    phone: true
  };
```

To bind the key value:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of status | keyvalue">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
  [(ngModel)]="item.key" />
        <div class="state">
            <label>{{item.value}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

It will only support after angular 6, because [keyvalue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe was introduced in 6.1

Then on each column:

```
<td *ngIf="status.id">{{tableList.Id}}</td>
```

Your link of stackblitz is using @angular/compiler@5.0.0, so that will not work for keyvalue pipe.

Hope it will give you the direction to proceed!